# Extract HH:MM PM from '2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z'

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

`2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z` in this string is the information that this time is `07:00 PM` with this being eastern time (ET), which appears correct as ET is 5 hours behind UTC. How can we (a) first convert from string to (datetime?, timestamp?), and then convert the resulting time object into `07:00 PM`? What has been tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

...which throws the error `time data '2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`. What is being done wrong here?

Comment: you are missing a Z. `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`

Comment: You could also include the timezone in the parsing by doing: `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'` which would give you the output: `datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: it doesn't get me quite all the way to `07:00 PM`

Comment: `datetime.fromisoformat('2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z'.replace('Z', '+00:00')).strftime('%I:%M %p')`? You might as well strip the Z if you don't care about the time zone (UTC).

Comment: We are looking for it to be eastern time zone, this is great but it does return UTC time zone

Comment: then parse *with* the Z and add `.astimezone(ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))` prior to strftime with ZoneInfo class from zoneinfo module. Now that's becoming multiple questions in one...

Comment: okay got it, yeah `datetime.strptime('2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').astimezone(ZoneInfo('America/New_York')).strftime('%I:%M %p')` gets me very close, although it is returning 6PM instead of 7PM, seems like perhaps something with daylight savings is off.

Comment: Do not use a literal Z ! Use `%z`. Z *ignores* the time zone / UTC

Answer (score 9):

Summarizing everything from the comments above:

```
datetime.strptime('2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').astimezone(ZoneInfo('America/New_York')).strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

returns exactly what we needed.